# ZendFramework 2: Locale Currency values in a form

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, locale

Is there any way to convert how a text input displays a currency in its value in correct locale number format from within the Form construct method or ViewHelper?

e.g.

1. value from database is 10000.50
2. In US or UK, is viewed as 10,000.50
3. In EUR is viewed as 10.000,50

I have been able to do the conversions in controllers, models and views, but haven't come across how do do it here.

Thanks

Aborgrove

Comment: Can you explain where you want to display the currency? Is it as a label?

Comment: Thanks Jurian, updated with more info.

Comment: Keeping the input variable, too, is a little more tricky. You'd have to read the UserSession to find his locale and then change / switch the validator for your input. The DefaultValue could be changed using the [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) (same as to revert the number into the right format to safe it to the DB)

Comment: Thanks Sam, my form's inputFilter is converting all values back to DECIMAL format based on the locale in order to be saved back to the DB. My issue is literally getting the locale conversion into the form render functionality. So I can keep the view as simple as possible: $this->formCollection($budget_form);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `Zend\I18n` component which ships formatters to format numbers. You can both use the `NumberFormat` for numbers in general and the `CurrencyFormat` for specifically currencies.

These formatters are living in the `Zend\I18n\View\Helper` domain, but are not dependant on the view actually. Therefore, you can just use them anywhere you want:

```
use Zend\I18n\View\Helper\CurrencyFormat;

$formatter = new CurrencyFormat;
$formatter->setLocale('en-US');

$currency  = $formatter(1234.56, 'EUR'); // "€1,234.56"
$currency  = $formatter(1234.56, 'USD'); // "$1,234.56"

$formatter->setLocale('nl-NL');
$currency  = $formatter(1234.56, 'EUR'); // "€ 1.234,56"
```

You have to be aware of two things:

1. The number formatting style is depending on the locale, so supply the correct locale (or set the default locale with `Locale::setDefault()`).
2. The "EUR" or "USD" is only for the signs, and together with the locale will be prepended or appended to the number formatted

You can simply use the `Zend\I18n\View\Helper\NumberFormat` if you only want to format the numbers without any currency code. More information about the formatting is available in the [manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.i18n.view.helpers.html).

Comment: Thanks Jurian, In order to maintain the simplest view e.g. echo $this->formCollection($budget_form); I think I need to create a custom form ViewHelper apply the conversion in there in order to keep the conversion away from the controller or the views themselves, do you agree?

Comment: *If* you want to display the form in a single line, yes: you have to create a custom display helper for that.